# how to call custom block in magento

Tags: magento-2.1, static-block, header

How to call custom block in header any help will be appreciated .

```
 <referenceBlock name="logo">
     <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="help">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="help" xsi:type="string">promo</argument>
        </arguments>
       </block>               
 </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have to get `argument name="block_id"`

```
<referenceBlock name="logo">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="help">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">promo</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>   
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: does not call this code

Comment: Have you create promo static block?

Comment: i just create in backend  content block i want to call it after logo in default.xml

Comment: you have to pass <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">promo</argument>  in your query

Comment: which in custom block page or default.xml

Comment: replace your xml with this one, <referenceBlock name="logo"> <arguments> <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument> <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument> </arguments> <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="help"> <arguments> <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">promo</argument> </arguments> </referenceBlock>

Comment: Have you solve issue or still error

Comment: does not work sr

Comment: i just comlete the  admin block and i want  to call as menu click after the logo and i call it in our theme default.xml file